# Improve UILabel text visibility in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8.1

I am showing the text on an UIImage in UITableViewCell, but UILabel text is dull. How to improve label text brightness? I have added Label on Image. I am also using Shadow image in label to make the text more visible, but the text is more dull in iPhone 6 Simulator.
How to manage it? And any other way to achieve this

Comment: UILabels are never dull during runtime. You need to provide more details how the label is created, configured and on what background placed. It is very likely that one of those points is the cause.

Comment: I am using storyboard so we drag the UILabel in TableViewCell. Cell contain  1 - Image that cover cell, 2- add label on image And I am using font "Avenir-Light"

Comment: Use shadowColor in your UILabel instead for your text. By setting a color that contrasts with your text color, it will be easier to read. You can also set a semi-transparent background color to your label in order to make it stand out. You could even use a blurred background, checkout Blur and Vibrancy.

Comment: Thanks @chrisben but when we use shadow color make text like a bold. I am using shadow image in behind Label . Any other solution

Answer (score 0):

And image or a description of what kind of "improvements" you are looking for would help to help you out better.

But the 2 most important things are probably font and color.

if you want to change the textColor. Use

```
myUILabel.textcolor = UIColor(red: 16/255.0, green: 177/255.0, blue: 216/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Obviously changing the RGB values to something that looks good in your app.

to change the font and fontsize use something like this:

```
myUILabel.font = UIFont(name: "BPreplay", size: 20)
```

Also it's always better to test on an actual device. Gives you a much better view on how it feels on the phone.

Comment: I am also use RGB color code and using "Avenir-Light" font , But my need is label text is  more readable. UILabel is Added on Image

Comment: Could you perhaps supply an image, it's difficult giving design suggestions based on text.

Comment: I can't upload screen shot because my account is new, show did not allow upload image.                                                                                               In UITableViewCell Image then Shadow image for label and label for text

Comment: you can give us a link to an image still :)

Comment: my requirement http://s22.postimg.org/iuj6f65sx/IMG_3.jpg and current image http://s29.postimg.org/vb3jywn07/current_Image.png